# How do I implement getsymbols function using for statement?

Tags: r

```
library(quantmod)
kospi = c('000020','000030','000040')
koslist = as.character(kospi)
koslist
startDate <<- as.Date("2017-01-01")
endDate <<- as.Date("2017-01-05")

for(i in koslist){
  assign('m','i',envir = .GlobalEnv) # set m Global global variable #Problem1
  tt = getSymbols(m, src = "google", from = startDate, to = endDate,env=NULL)
ff = data.frame(tt)
 kk = ff$I.Close #Problem2
 print(kk)
 }
```

I wanted to make for statement code to use getSymbols function(function to get stock information). But I encountered two problem.

1. I couldn't set the Global variable in for statement. If I do not set the Global variable, function got me a wrong data. But I still got a wrong data nevertheless I set the Global variable. I don't know Problem.
2. Even if I solve the problem1, I have a column name problem. Yahoo got me a data like this. Every column name have 'X'(+Global variables(stockcode)). I don't know for statement'Global variable to column name.

   ```
              X005930.Open X005930.High X005930.Low X005930.Close
   2017-01-02      1799000      1812000     1794000       1805000
   2017-01-03      1814000      1831000     1801000       1824000
   2017-01-04      1825000      1826000     1805000       1808000
   2017-01-05      1803000      1803000     1777000       1778000
   ```

I am not sure approach like that. I want repeat the getsymbols function. I struggle with this a couple of weeks. Please let me know solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your script.  In your statement:

```
assign('m','i',envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

You are assigning the literal string `'i'` to the variable `m`, not a stock symbol.  Secondly, the first argument in `getSymbols` is a stock symbol.   000020, 000030 or 000040 are not valid stock symbols.

Try this:

```
library(quantmod)
symbol_list = c('AAPL','GOOGL','MSFT')
startDate <<- as.Date("2017-01-01")
endDate <<- as.Date("2017-01-05")

for(i in symbol_list){
    tt = getSymbols(i, src = "google", from = startDate, to = endDate,env=NULL)
    print(tt)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. sorry to bother you, one more question. Korea stock symbol is nurmeric like this(005930)# samsung electronics code. –//  I have saved codes in kospi2.xlsx(, and I call that in R. but that code does not Loop and put the wrong value return.

Comment: library(quantmod)
require(xlsx)
symbol_list = read.xlsx("C:/Users/Kun/Desktop/kospi2.xlsx",1, header=F)
aa = c(symbol_list)
aa

startDate <<- as.Date("2017-01-01")
endDate <<- as.Date("2017-01-05")

for(i in aa){
  tt = getSymbols("i", src = "google", from = startDate, to = endDate,env=NULL, auto.assign = F)
  print(tt)
}

Comment: > startDate <<- as.Date("2017-01-01")
> endDate <<- as.Date("2017-01-05")
> for(i in aa){
+   tt = getSymbols("i", src = "google", from = startDate, to = endDate,env=NULL, auto.assign = F)
+   print(tt)
+ }
           I.Open I.High I.Low I.Close I.Volume
2017-01-03   2.71   2.86  2.71    2.85   204145
2017-01-04   2.89   3.14  2.76    3.10   429362
2017-01-05   3.10   3.15  2.93    3.01   232793

Comment: xlsx file like this.list. 000020
000030
000040
000050
000060
000070
000075
000080
000087
000100
000105
000120
000140
000145
000150
000155
000157
000180
000210
000215
000220
000225
000227